# HTML: Two images on the same line while resizing as the window resizes

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to put two portrait images on the same line, and keep them there, even if I resize the window, they should resize too...

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Note: I'm looking for this info to use on tumblr.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sadly your question lacks any effort. Can you show us what you have tried? For clarification, the answer will involve CSS and isn't Tumblr related.

Comment: use % widths and heights

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/49tvt/

Comment: @3rror404 Yes, like that, but force the two images on the same row.

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks and sorry about that. I've searched all around and tried different things but didn't work. So far, I only have this <img alt="" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/mmuqmFWqneZGB6f7m21hDWdfHIyGXRX5A5tcY-toIIJ1=s400" /> <img alt="" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1kePfxcm4vE1sj-NmsJsRQgtx6bx4tRC3ax9gXYCjxam=s400" /></p> I thought it was supposed to have the two photos on the same row, so I can open a tumblr post and see them like I wanted to. Hope I explained well.

Comment: They should be on the same row unless you are using an old version of IE. Remove the border and they will be. I just added that as an example

Comment: @3rror404 i'm using firefox, but, yest, with the border line removed it worked great... Now I just need to figure out how to edit css in tumblr posts (only found html there). I'll look for it.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your question is a bit weird and hard to understand. Might wanna fix that.

If you're just wondering how to make the images stay on a line and resize with the browser window, you can assign them a width value with a % property.

Like this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FredrikAugust/xz3L8/)

```
img {
    width:30%;
    /* 
    eventually max-width and/or min-width 
    */
}
```